# Why is 五右衛門 read "goemon"?

Tags: etymology, readings

Why is the name 五右衛門 read as ごえもん?
How can the three kanji 五右衛 be read with only two syllables?

Comment: That originates from the name of the Court's government position.
http://kira03.fc2web.com/zatsugaku/001kanshoku3.html 左衛門 右衛門

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Originally, these kanji were thought to be pronounced as:

> 右衛門: *u we mon*

But since Japanese *u* and consonant *w* have little difference, the actual pronunciation was like:

> 右衛門: *wwe~we mon*

Later, undergone the phonological change that merged *wi, we, wo* into *i, e, o*:

> 右衛門: *e mon*

So the truth is 右 and 衛 share a single syllable, but the fact has been obscured by the sound change.

Answer (score 14):

[Some](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q143434759) [people](http://twitter.com/#!/_ryu9/status/11886981072) say that *goemon* (五右衛門) and *iemon* (伊右衛門) are pronounced like that since it's hard to pronounce 2 or 3 continuous vowel sounds, as are supposed to be read as *g**oue**mon* (ごうゑもん) / ***iue***mon (いうゑもん) per syllable.

Comment: Was the original pronunciation *goue* or *gōe*? I guess actually *goue*, same as *iue*? That's indeed something of a tongue twister... :) Makes sense.

Comment: @deceze, I also think *goue* too, but I couldn't find it in dictionaries for reference, since those are names of people.